# Comma use in a list where all the items are new

Tags: commas, lists

Which one is appropriate:

1) He was given a new bat, ball, and glove.

2) He was given a new, bat, ball, and glove

3) He was given a new bat, a new ball, and a new glove.

Comment: Number 2 is not correct. Whether one uses 1, or 3 would seem to depend on your interpretation of how your listener will read it. E.g. does a bat, ball and glove normally come as a set? If so then 1 would seem to suffice. But if you have any doubt that your listener, or reader, may misinterpret it as 'a new bat, but old ball and old glove, then I would use 3. In short it depends how emphatic you want to be about the newness of the items.

Answer (score 4):

3) is unambiguous, but is more wordy than strictly necessary.

2) is not how you would express this idea. You would never separate a single adjective from its referent(s) with a comma.

1) is the most idiomatic way of conveying your intended meaning. Preceding the entire list with 'new' as you have done implicitly attaches the adjective to each of its individual elements.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the fish and taught me to fish all at the same time.

Comment: @user101830 - Glad to help.  :)

Comment: Also comparatively short, totally unambiguous, and idiomatically commonplace as an explicit way of avoiding potential ambiguity, *"He was given a bat, ball, and glove - all new"*.

Comment: It should be noted that the rules for placing commas in lists have changed several times in the past century.  Notably, the "authorities" removed the comma before "and" in the late 50s, then restored it perhaps 1970.  Rules for associating/distributing adjectives were juggled at the same time, if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: @HotLicks - A couple of points: 1) There are no *rule-making* linguistic authorities as such for English; and 2) The usage of commas in lists is in any case affected by too many factors for it to be possible to have one-size-fits-all rules governing it. See, for instance, the discussion and comments in [this article](http://mentalfloss.com/article/33637/best-shots-fired-oxford-comma-wars) at mentalfloss.com.

Comment: @ErikKowal - So, no Strunk & White?  No Cambridge Grammar?  No Longman?

Comment: Those dudes don't own me, man.

Comment: Different people and different institutions may shift their allegiances with regard to a particular punctuation style, but the leaders of the two schools of thought on the serial (Oxford) comma in the United States—the Chicago Manual of Style (in favor) and the Associated Press Stylebook (opposed)—have been consistent in their mutually contradictory advice for many decades. The U.S. Government Printing Office currently favors AP (no serial comma) and may have favored Chicago before that, though I don't know whether that's the case. As Erik Kowal says, it's a style issue.

Comment: @HotLicks - You might be interested to read [what the linguist Geoffrey Pullum has to say](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497) about Strunk & White: it ain't pretty. As for the others: I don't discount the expertise embodied in Longmans or *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (indeed, Geoffrey Pullum is one of the co-authors of the latter), but even they have no *official* standing; nor are their perspectives immune from criticism or revision.

Comment: I'm simply recalling, best I can remember, 4th grade, ca 1959, when the teacher returned from a "continuing education" session (or whatever they called it back then) and rattled off the new (to her and us) rules about commas.  The comma before "and" was gone.

Comment: @HotLicks - Some 'rules' are based on the observation of empirical evidence and/or practices that take account of what approach is most sensible one to follow for a given case; others (presumably including whatever so-called rules your teacher had been indoctrinated with) attempt to force the language into conforming to them, rather than being derived from (or based on) the way the language is *actually* used. If you haven't already done so, I really recommend you to look at the Mental Floss article I linked to for examples of the kind of mess you can get into by slavishly following 'rules'.

Comment: I'm well aware of the Pist/Dist thing.  To the Pist the rules are revealed from God and you'll go to Hell if you break them.  To the Dist the rules are what everyone does, and everyone will unfriend you if you break them.

Comment: @HotLicks - Good. From what you wrote before, I wasn't sure you had understood that (though *I* would *never* unfriend you).  :)